# CSS -moz-available on select not working

Tags: css

On second page in this website http://181.224.135.163/~tommasom/node/add/rapporto-di-lavoro
I added on first select list ("Vitto e alloggio") the CSS rule `width: -moz-available`.

The same rule should work to the second select list "Variazioni", but it doesn't.

Why the rule on the second case is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real quick, you'll need to insert

```
body{ overflow-x:hidden; }
```

for that second page, there's a lot of horizontal scrolling. Unfortunately I can't find the style that you're mentioning. It's the first dropdown on the second page yeah? (click next page once I follow your link)

Comment: I added to body `overflow-x:hidden` but the select "Variazioni" is still over the container...The first dropdown ("Vitto e alloggio") is working, the second one no :(

Comment: On tr.odd .form-item add max-width:150px; and set the width of the selects to 100%, the -moz-available appears to not suit this case. I don't normally use it so I can't really say why

Comment: Delighted to hear it helped you