# -moz-available isn't working in Firefox like its analog in Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, browser-detection, stretch

Surprised this isn't covered yet on SO.

Looked here:
[CSS -moz-available on select not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991065/css-moz-available-on-select-not-working)
and
[CSS -moz-available equivalent in Webkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383923/css-moz-available-equivalent-in-webkit)
... to no avail :(

Anyway.

In Chrome the **background is extending down to the bottom of the page** per requirements.
The background covers down to the bottom of the page like so.
[image: Notice the -webkit-fill-available]

As soon as I uncheck -webkit-fill-available it looks like this (as it should)...
[image: Notice the -webkit-fill-available is unchecked]

In Firefox I tried using the analog, -moz-available but it does not work as I expected.
[image: Notice the -moz-available]
...I have tried going through the other options Firefox has available.
[image: Firefox options]
...they don't work either.

I was about to browser or feature sniff and just implement this half-fix.
[image: Just extending that card down, taking up space so the background will extend with it]
Here I am just extending that card down, taking up space so the background will extend with it.

So I'm just checking with you guys to see if I am missing something here before I go sniffing :)

Thanks for any insights! Hopefully, we can clear this up for everyone else too, please edit to generalize if I missed something.

Index (Parent/Bootstrapped) Template default in all angular cli applications:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GWConnect</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Template:

```
<!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between static-top">
  <img class="navbar-brand  auto-margin-brand" src="./../../assets/images/CompanyLogos/temp-logo.png">
  <form class="form-inline login-nav-form responsive-login-nav-form">
    <input name="email" class="form-control login-nav-input-box mr-sm-2" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Login">
    <button type="button" class="btn login-nav-input-btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" [disabled]='!email.valid' (click)="login($event)">Sign In</button>
  </form>
</nav> -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between static-top">
  <img class="navbar-brand  auto-margin-brand" src="./../../assets/images/CompanyLogos/temp-logo.png">
  <form novalidate #loginError #f='ngForm' id="myform" (ngSubmit)="login(email, $event)" class="form-inline login-nav-form responsive-login-nav-form">
    <input required #email="ngModel" name="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$"
      ngModel class="form-control login-nav-input-box mr-sm-2" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Login">

    <button type="button" class="btn login-nav-input-btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" (click)="login(email, $event)">Sign In</button>
    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn login-nav-input-btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" [disabled]='!f.valid' (click)="login($event)">Sign In</button> -->
  </form>
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="pt-4 landing overlay" id='landing'>

  <!-- /.row -->
  <div class='row center'>
    <div class="card text-center special-card no-y-margin-padding">
      <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white hidden-mobile"></div>
      <div class="card-body">

        <!-- BEGIN PORTALS -->

        <div class="row carousel-portal">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-border portal-style" [ngClass]="{'feature-nav-button': portalState =='portal-a', 'click-portal-style': portalState =='portal-a'}"
            (click)="portalState = 'portal-a'; changeColor($event,ele1,ele2)" id="portal-a" (mouseover)="changeColor($event,ele1,ele2)"
            (mouseout)="changeColor($event,ele1,ele2)">
            <!-- <img src="./../../assets/images/Icons/eta.png"> -->
            <span #ele1 id="portal-a" class="icon-eta landing-icon black"></span>
            <H6 #ele2 id="portal-a" class="pt-4 black">CAR ESTIMATED TIME OF ARRIVALS</H6>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-border portal-style" [ngClass]="{'feature-nav-button': portalState =='portal-b', 'click-portal-style': portalState =='portal-b'}"
            (click)="portalState = 'portal-b'; changeColor($event,ele3,ele4)" id="portal-b" (mouseover)="changeColor($event,ele3,ele4)"
            (mouseout)="changeColor($event,ele3,ele4)">
            <!-- <img src="./../../assets/images/Icons/schedule-car.png"> -->
            <span #ele3 id="portal-b" class="icon-schedule-cars landing-icon black"></span>
            <H6 #ele4 id="portal-b" class="pt-4 black">SET UP CAR SCHEDULES</H6>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-border portal-style" [ngClass]="{'feature-nav-button': portalState =='portal-c','click-portal-style': portalState =='portal-c'}"
            (click)="portalState= 'portal-c'; changeColor($event,ele5,ele6)" id="portal-c" (mouseover)="changeColor($event,ele5,ele6)"
            (mouseout)="changeColor($event,ele5,ele6)">
            <!-- <img src="./../../assets/images/Icons/demurrage.png"> -->
            <span #ele5 id="portal-c" class="icon-demurrage landing-icon black"></span>
            <H6 #ele6 id="portal-c" class="pt-4 black">VIEW DEMURRAGE CHARGES</H6>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-border portal-style" [ngClass]="{'feature-nav-button': portalState =='portal-d', 'click-portal-style': portalState =='portal-d'}"
            (click)="portalState= 'portal-d'; changeColor($event,ele7,ele8)" id="portal-d" (mouseover)="changeColor($event,ele7,ele8)"
            (mouseout)="changeColor($event,ele7,ele8)">
            <!-- <img src="./../../assets/images/Icons/more.png"> -->
            <span #ele7 id="portal-d" class="icon-more landing-icon black"></span>
            <H6 #ele8 id="portal-d" class="pt-4 black">AND MORE...</H6>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left carousel-chevron" (click)='portalStateChangeRight()' aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-right carousel-chevron" (click)='portalStateChangeLeft()' aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>

        <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
        <div class="row center landing-page-featured-info" *ngIf="portalState === 'portal-a'">
          <div class="col-md-6 carousel-content">
            <img src="../../assets/images/map.jpg" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
            <h4>Car Estimated Time of Arrivals</h4>
            <p>Answering the question of when your cars are arriving, G&W Connect offers both dynamic and historical estimated
              time of arrivals for both incoming railcars and outbound rail shipments.
            </p>
            <p>
              View your cars' last movement times, whether they are en route, inbound, or outbound, and when your cars will move to the
              next station or road.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row center landing-page-featured-info" *ngIf="portalState === 'portal-b'">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="../../assets/images/train-bridge-dam.jpg" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="
                col-md-6
                text-left
                ">
            <h4>Set Up Car Schedules</h4>
            <p>Need specific types of railcars at a particular time and place? On G&W Connect you can look up the availability
              of the kind of cars you need in your geographic area of interest and view specific information about them.
              With this information, you can request and schedule your cars to be where you need them when you need them.
            </p>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row center landing-page-featured-info" *ngIf="portalState === 'portal-c'">
          <div class="col-md-6
                ">
            <img src="../../assets/images/tankers.jpg" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6
                text-left
                ">
            <h4>View Demurrage Charges</h4>
            <p>G&W Connect allows you to review current demurrage, storage, and accessorial charges as well as view how much
              time you have before additional demurrage charges start.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row center landing-page-featured-info" *ngIf="portalState === 'portal-d'">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="../../assets/images/temp-logo-lg-black.png" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Call to Action Well -->

</div>

<div class='validation-modal-overlay' *ngIf="seeEmailInvalidModal">
  <div class='validation-modal-window small-modal'>
    <div class="validation-modal-toolbar">
      <!-- <div class="validation-modal-close" (click)='closeError(loginError)'> -->
      <div class="validation-modal-close" (click)='resetSeeEmailInvalidModal()'>
        <span class="icon-x"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='validation-modal-content'>
      Please enter a valid email address.
    </div>
    <div class="center-ok">
      <button class="ok-button" (click)="resetSeeEmailInvalidModal()">Ok</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Scoped Stylesheet

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.auto-margin-brand{
  margin-left: 15px;
}

/* .form-control{
  padding-left: 30px;
} */

.landing {
  width: 100%;
  height: stretch;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  /* margin-top: -78px; */
}

.overlay{
  z-index: 0;
  background: #000000ff;
}

.form-control.ng-touched.ng-invalid{
  border: 1px solid red;
  opacity: .5;
}
.validation-modal-overlay-IsHidden{
display:hidden !important;
}
.validation-modal-overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #00000055;
}
/* .validation-modal-window{
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  right: 36%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.validation-modal-toolbar{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.validation-modal-close{
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  border-left:2px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  .validation-modal-content{
  padding:30px;
  text-align: center;
} */

.back1{
  background: linear-gradient(#00000055,#00000055), url('./../../assets/images/background/train-background1.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.back2{
  background: linear-gradient(#00000055,#00000055), url('./../../assets/images/background/train-background2.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.back3{
  background: linear-gradient(#00000055,#00000055), url('./../../assets/images/background/train-background3.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.back4{
  background: linear-gradient(#00000055,#00000055), url('./../../assets/images/background/train-background4.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.back5{
  background: linear-gradient(#00000055,#00000055), url('./../../assets/images/background/train-background5.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.back6{
  background: linear-gradient(#00000055,#00000055), url('./../../assets/images/background/train-background6.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.back7{
  background: linear-gradient(#00000055,#00000055), url('./../../assets/images/background/train-background7.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.back8{
  background: linear-gradient(#00000055,#00000055), url('./../../assets/images/background/train-background8.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.back9{
  background: linear-gradient(#00000055,#00000055), url('./../../assets/images/background/train-background9.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 0px;
  flex-direction: row;
}

/* .card-body .row{
  display: block;
} */

.carousel-chevron{
  display:none;
}.fa-chevron-left{
  left: 0px;
}.fa-chevron-right{
  right: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:575px) {

.card .card-body .carousel-portal {
  height: 24vh;
}

  .card .card-body .landing-page-featured-info{
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .card-body .carousel-portal .feature-nav-button{
    width: 60% !important;
    margin-right: 20% !important;
  }

  .navbar{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

.responsive-login-nav-form{
  /* padding-left: 11.5vw !important; */
  /* padding-right: 11.5vw !important; */
  background: #D68110 !important;
  padding-right: 13% !important;
  padding-left: 13% !important;
}
.login-nav-input-box{
  margin-left: unset !important;
  margin-right: unset !important;
}
.login-nav-input-btn{
  margin-left: unset !important;
  margin-right: unset !important;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 575px){

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {


.landing{
  height: fit-content; /* needed because background image is no longer there */
}

.carousel-portal .feature-nav-button{
  width: 80% !important;
  margin-right: 10% !important;
}

.no-y-margin-padding{
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.card .card-body .landing-page-featured-info{
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.hidden-mobile{
  display:none;
}

.portal-style{
  opacity:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2vh;
  right: 0vw;
  animation: opacity 1s;
  z-index: 0;
}
.click-portal-style{
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  color:black;
  }

.auto-margin-brand{
  margin: auto;
}

  /* CARD CHANGES */
.landing{
  padding-top: 0px !important;
}
.center{
  width:unset !important;
}
.card-header:first-child{
  border-radius:0px;
}

.carousel-portal{
  border-bottom:  3px solid #000000;
  height: 22vh;
  width: 85vw;
  margin: auto;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /* margin-left: -93vh; */
}

.carousel-content {
margin-top: 0px;
  }

.carousel-chevron{
  color: #c6c6c5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  display:unset;
  font-size:4em;
}

.back1{
  background: white;
}
.back2{
  background: white;
}
.back3{
  background: white;
}
.back4{
  background: white;
}
.back5{
  background: white;
}
.back6{
  background: white;
}
.back7{
  background: white;
}
.back8{
  background: white;
}
.back9{
  background: white;
}

}

.trapezoid-test{
  position: absolute;
    /* z-index: 0; */
    height: 101%;
    /* left: 0px; */
    right: -1px;
    top: -1px;
}

.login-nav-form{
  /* padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 50px; */
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;

  padding:2px;
  background: url('./../../assets/images/trapezoid.png') no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.login-nav-input-box{
  width:70vw;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-radius:0px;
}.login-nav-input-box{
  width:70vw;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-radius:0px;
}
.login-nav-input-btn {
  align-self: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #D68110;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.login-nav-input-btn:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: white;
}

.vertical-center
{
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /* .col-md-border:not(:last-child) {
      border-right: 3px solid #000000;
  } */
  .col-md-border + .col-md-border {
      border-left:  3px solid #000000;
      margin-left: -1px;
  }
}

.card {
  border-style: none;
  width:100%;
}

.special-card {
    background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.9);
  }

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: #000000!important;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0;
}

/* .trapezoid {
  border-bottom: 78px solid #D68110;
  border-right: 35px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 475px;
  right: 0px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -39px;
} */

.landing-page-featured-info {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.feature-nav-button {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffe834 35%, #ffe834 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}

.landing-icon {
  font-size: 65pt;
  color: black;
}

.landing-icon:before {
  color: black;
}

.form-control:focus{
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #ffffff40;
}

.gray,
.gray:before{
  color: #797779;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.black,
.black:before{
  color: #000;
}

.card-body{
  height: auto;
}

.img-fix{
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.portal-style{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Global Stylesheet (incomplete per SO body limit)

```
*{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
}

body,html {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  display: flex;
}

/* GW BRANDING */
:root{
  --gworange: #d68110;

  --gwyellow: #f3d111;

  --gwblack: #000;
  --gwblack85: #000000D5;

  --gwdarkgray: #797779;

  --gwlightgray:#cfcfce;

  --gwblue:#275173;
  --gwblue95lt:#ecf3f8;

  --success:#93b558;

  --error:#ba3a32;

  --highlight:#ef992a;

  --highlightblue:#54d3ee;

  --transparent:#00000000;

/*
  --sidebar:  50px;
  --sidebarBlade: calc(49vw - var(--sidebar));
  --sidebarFullblade:  calc(96vw - var(--sidebar));
  --absoluteCrumb: calc(100vw - var(--sidebar)); */

  --sidebarBlade:  48vw;
  --sidebarFullblade:  96vw;
  --sidebarHoverOpacity: 0;
  --hamburgerHoverOpacity: 100;
  --sidebarHoverDisplay: none;
}
/* form .ng-touched.ng-invalid{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px var(--error);
} */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: var(--gwdarkgray);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: var(--gwlightgray);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-button{
  background-color: orange;
} */
/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece{
  background-color:blue;
} */
/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner{
  background-color: red;
} */


.e-input-focus{
  background: red;
}


ul,li{
  list-style-type: none !important;
  /* padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important; */
}
```

Comment: Please include actual code, not screenshots of code. Read this: [MCVE]

Comment: no code no chocolate.  what's the code around your issue ? how did you build the layout, float,display,position,.... ?

Comment: code is provided now

Comment: Was the error ever figured out? I ran into the same issue. :(

Comment: this was 3 jobs ago haha so I don't have access to that code. Try: `height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;` in the containing div or something like this. Play around